# Android sqlite - Retornar _id logado ListView apenas um valor selecionado usando condição Where

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, select

Boa noite pessoal, sou novato aqui, sou novato em programação Android, porém decidi fazer o meu TCC, um projeto em Android. por estar fazendo sozinho, encontrando material na internet, sem ter aulas de Android, estou indo até que bem (ou não), mas encalhei num determinado ponto.

Tenho uma ListView que me retorna os dados do banco SQLite.

Se eu deixar o SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario; ele me traz todos os usuários cadastrados no banco, mas eu queria apenas deixar aparecendo o usuário que fez o login no sistema.

ou seja, eu queria fazer uma condição dentro do Select, ficando "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE _id = id que está logado no sistema.

porém não consigo, já perdi dois dias procurando um jeito de fazer, já mudei a estrutura do código e estou perdido.

Bom, meu código está aí.

```
public class Area_Usuario extends ActionBarActivity{
private String TABLE;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.area_usuario);
    TABLE = "tbl_usuario";


    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = db.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = ("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE);
    Cursor cursor= db1.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{String.valueOf(usuario.get_id())});
    String[] from = {"nome", "email", "senha"};
    int[] to = {R.id.Usuario_RowNome, R.id.Usuario_RowEmail, R.id.Usuario_RowSenha};
    ListView ltUsuario = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDadosUsuario);
    SimpleCursorAdapter ad = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.usuario_row, cursor, from, to, 1);
    ltUsuario.setAdapter(ad);
    db1.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quer usar a cláusula *WHERE* terá de indicá-la na Query:

```
String sql = ("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE _id = ?");
Cursor cursor= db1.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{String.valueOf(usuario.get_id())});
```

O `?` é um *'placeholder'* para receber o valor indicado em `new String[]{String.valueOf(usuario.get_id())}`

Sugiro que, em alternativa a *db.rawQuery*, use os métodos que **SQLiteDatabase** disponibiliza para as operações *CRUD*.

No caso da leitura de dados deve usar uma das variantes de [SQLiteDatabase.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

Ficaria assim:

```
Cursor cursor = db1.query(TABLE, null, "_id = ?",
                           new String[]{String.valueOf(usuario.get_id())},null,null,null);
```

Comment: ramaral, entendi sim essa forma de utilizar o Cursor, até achei melhor, eu digito usuário e senha, e efetuo o login, mas ainda meu ListView aparece em branco, ou seja, acredito que ele não está carregando os dados da.

    String[] from = {.....};
        int[] to = {.....};

Comment: Você está a instanciar a classe *Usuario* e não lhe atribui nenhum valor, por isso `usuario.get_id()` irá retornar sempre `0`. Se não souber o id do usuário terá de procurar, na tabela, o usuário pelo nome e não pelo id.

Comment: Não entendo por que você quer utilizar um *ListView* quando o resultado da query irá ser apenas um registo.

Comment: Posso retornar os dados do usuário em um TextView simples(no caso um TextView para cada dado retornado)??

Comment: claro que pode. Use os métodos `getInt(int columnIndex)`, `getDouble(int columnIndex)`, [`getString(int columnIndex)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29), etc, para obter os dados referentes a cada coluna.

Comment: Faltou indicar, no meu comentário anterior, que os métodos a que faço referência são da classe *Cursor*

Comment: consegui resolver meu problema, invés de eu trazer os dados do usuário pelo Id, resolvi trazer por e-mail, porém preciso apenas agora, conseguir fazer uma verificação se o e-mail já está cadastrado no banco de dados, para o que o usuário não consiga fazer duas vezes o cadastro do mesmo e-mail.
coloque o email em putExtra na tela 1 e na tela 2 eu recebi o email com o getExtra e fiz a query usando o email recebido da tela 1.

Comment: Essa é a forma usual de verificar se um usuário está cadastrado, quando o *username* é o e-mail. Não esqueça de verificar a *password*. O conjunto *username* e *password* é o que identifica um utilizador.